# Uniform convergence and differentiability of $\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{nx}(1-e^{-\frac{x}{n}}) $

Tags: power-series, uniform-convergence

I have a problem with the power series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{nx}(1-e^{-\frac{x}{n}})~~~~~~x\in(0, \infty)$$

I have to prove that it's uniformely convergent and determine whether the sum is differentiable.

If the series is defined by $f(x)$, if I find $f(x)<a_n $ and $\sum a_n $ is convergent, then $\sum f(x) $ is uniformely convergent (Weierstrass). To determine whether the sum is differentiable, I have to determine whether the sum of derivatives is convergent. However, how can I do that? Can I split it to:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{nx} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{nx}e^{-\frac{x}{n}} $$

Does it help anything?

Answer (score 1):

No, because $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {1\over n}$ is $\infty$. Its derivative is $$f'(x){=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[-\frac{1}{nx^2}(1-e^{-\frac{x}{n}})+\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{n}}}{n^2x}\right]
\\=-{f(x)\over x}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{n}}}{n^2x}
}
$$
Note that the second limit is convergent compared to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: What about the first limit? What about uniform convergence?

Comment: Is the domain of $f$, $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: Yes, I will edit the post

Comment: Yes, it is. Note that for $x>0$ and $0<\alpha<1$$${1-\alpha\over n}x\le 1-e^{-x\over n}\le {x\over n}$$hence $$(1-\alpha)\sum_{n=M}^\infty{1\over n^2}\le\sum_{n=M}^\infty\cdots \le\sum_{n=M}^\infty{1\over n^2}$$